# Check if a column's value is null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can't believe I am stuck with this but how can I check that value I am returning is null in select statement

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TU.Tagged FROM TopicUser TU 
          WHERE TU.TopicId = @TopicId and TU.UserId = @UserId)
BEGIN
    --do stuff
END
```

The value of `TU.Tagged` is `NULL` but yet it does go into the condition. In mind it does not exist.

Comment: The `IF EXISTS` only checks if a **row** that matches your criteria (`WHERE TU.TopicId = @TopicId AND TU.UserId = @UserId`) exists - if it does, it returns true - no matter what value `TU.tagged` has. The `SELECT` inside the `IF EXISTS()` **does NOT** really return anything other than a `True` if at least one row matching the `WHERE` criteria exists.... and your current `WHERE` clause is saying *nothing* about `TU.tagged` having to be not null....

Comment: I thought that much now that I think about it for a sec...thanks, silly of me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you need something like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TU.Tagged 
          FROM TopicUser TU 
          WHERE TU.TopicId = @TopicId 
               AND TU.UserId = @UserId 
               AND TU.Tagged IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    --do stuff

END
```

Otherwise, you're checking only if records meeting your criteria exist, but those records could have a `NULL` value in the `TU.Tagged` column.

Answer (score 6):

Solution 1 :
    Use IsNULL() Function, When below query return null value IsNULL function replace null value with 0 and if condition treated as False.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT IsNULL(TU.Tagged,0) FROM TopicUser TU 
          WHERE TU.TopicId = @TopicId and TU.UserId = @UserId)
BEGIN  
END
```

Solution 2 : 
    Use (IS NULL OR IS NOT NULL) Property.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TU.Tagged FROM TopicUser TU 
          WHERE TU.TopicId = @TopicId and TU.UserId = @UserId
          AND TU.Tagged IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN

END
```

Answer (score 3):

To check that something exists you can simply say:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TABLE WHERE ID = '2')
```

This simply returns a 1 if the record exists. For you the record exists but the column is null. You will need to check on  the ID of the user. By this I mean even if something is null then it still treats it as existing.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ISNULL(). when the select query return null for a value and if you want to replace it with O you can use below query.

```
    IF EXISTS(SELECT ISNULL(TU.Tagged,0) FROM TopicUser TU 
          WHERE TU.TopicId = @TopicId and TU.UserId = @UserId)
BEGIN
    --do stuff
END
```

As Like this You can replace the null with any value you want.